# How to implement a TypeScript generic type for nested properties that resolves to their types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to create a generic type that resolves to the type of a nested property

Say I have a configuration type

```
type Config = {
  parent: {
    child: boolean
  }
}
```

I would like something similar to

```
type ChildConfigType = NestedType<Config, 'parent.child'> // boolean
type ParentConfigType = NestedType<Config, 'parent'> // {child: boolean}
```

I have a basic implementation for non nested types

```
function getProp<
    Type extends object,
    Key extends keyof Type
>(key: Key): Type[Key] {
    return {} as Type[Key]
}

getProp<Config>('parent')
```

I also have non nested helper types that work

```
type PropsOf<
    Type extends object
> = keyof Type

type TypeOfProp<
    Type extends object,
    Key extends PropsOf<Type>
> = Type[Key]

function getPropWithHelpers<
    Type extends object,
    Key extends PropsOf<Type>
>(key: Key): TypeOfProp<Type, Key> {
    return {} as TypeOfProp<Type, Key>
}
```

I also have a NestedPropsOf helper that resolves to a flattened union of the nested properties

```
type NestedPropsOf<Type extends object> =
  {
    [key in keyof Type & (string | number)]: Type[key] extends object
    ? `${key}` | `${key}.${NestedPropsOf<Type[key]>}`
    : `${key}`
  }[keyof Type & (string | number)]

type NestedConfigProps = NestedPropsOf<Config> // 'parent' | 'parent.child'
```

And I am trying to implement a function with the signature

```
function getNestedProp<
    Type extends object,
    Key extends NestedPropsOf<Type>
>(key: Key): NestedTypeOfProp<Type, Key> {
    return {} as NestedTypeOfProp<Type, Key>
}


getNestedProp<Config>('parent.child')
```

I am starting to believe this is not possible because the types can't directly manipulate strings so I cannot remove the first segment of the path.

[Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeAoKQqMAQwCcIFgAuXAohgYwAsUAbAE1oCM442IJBPUIBfPOLxIArgkbAUiKGgjAACmThgAPCKgAVcNAgAPYJQ4BnKHG4ArCPIA0egNIQQUU%20YRWoAaw84JAMjPAA%20AApAkFp3EABKWkNIAG14gF06BgpgaTIEXFEoEmsUiHSPDIk8WoB6OqgAVUsUBAxmCDZIMihQSEta-ugNLUsAeSRdBnKvMwtrWwd5CKwAoJDyoaNQyEnRnT1Z7wWbe0dgFwZ4uZ8-A4mp8vDV7HLKkGqpWXlFQpV1JowAB1FDAZgACS6PUs0yIx3mvkW52cbg8t1OD0m2meEWiHjiHiSuwg%20yBOKMTig8XC2SIuXyhRwxVKJLJWgpkCpNJq9UaLTaGAQEEs5g4UE63QgZEGeGGUAAciKxVinjsTkizstgLTMPR8AxUjEoG11iBgiSoAAyKCRUVkQVQAA%20UAQ0gAttxpQkMskjEaqhjNUsLnoAPxQAAGABIcDFRJHnVHY-GAHSxpWiiAcVWcioxDLhBN6WgxuMeYtiAPmzY7G124AO9pJt2e71feUAWRADzWmZVQMe2hwpAoVFoOBY7C4UF4-EECFEohecp2-ez5XZhxm6sRfhDqOu6I1fnXOcH2OeSftgtedMIDSgAHdmCRgLz5WpyJRgLNsGfNyQA5tHgZB0CpAByUcfwgl55RgVhOD-RVlQ3IwtxAxBUDQSDoKoVMp04WDahkOQFCUAEz2Ao5dzuZFtSuIgbhPawqIvNVIBeKIYkJRJaAA9CgPJcpuQ8WkDXpVRGSKEpWNQjhAOAkTqTEiQgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/we89gW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to manipulate strings using [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals) and [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) keyword.

Utilities:

`Dot` is used to concatenate two strings with `.`:

```
type Dot<T extends string, U extends string> = "" extends U ? T : `${T}.${U}`;
```

`StopFields` is the type on which we should stop going further in the types; in our case, those are primitives:

```
type StopFields = string | number | boolean | symbol;
```

`PathToFields` returns all possible paths to properties of the passed type using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). It ignores arrays, which can be adjusted.

```
type PathsToFields<T> = T extends StopFields
  ? ""
  : {
      [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]: NonNullable<T[K]> extends Array<any>
        ? never
        : K | Dot<K, PathsToFields<T[K]>>;
    }[Extract<keyof T, string>];
```

Implementation:

```
type NestedType<T, Path extends PathsToFields<T>> = Path extends keyof T
  ? T[Path]
  : Path extends `${infer Property extends keyof T & string}.${infer SubField}`
  ? SubField extends PathsToFields<T[Property]>
    ? NestedType<T[Property], SubField>
    : never
  : never;
```

`NestedType` expects a type and its paths to fields. It first checks if the path is the property of the object, in that case, returns the type under that property, otherwise splits the path with `.` where the left part should be the key of the passed object and the part after the `.` is the remaining path. If all conditions are true, we invoice `NestedType` for the property that we got from splitting the path and passing the remaining path.

Usage:

```
type ChildConfigType = NestedType<Config, "parent.child">; // boolean
type ParentConfigType = NestedType<Config, "parent">; // {child: boolean}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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)

Comment: This works great. Just out of curiosity though how would you handle arrays?

Comment: it depends if you want pass any number or you are using tuples and the indexes are already known at the compile time